# Android Firestore cannot get FirestoreInstance

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set up the Firstore API with my Android project however when I try to call `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()` I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<clinit>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:150)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:70)
    at ip.travelaid.backend.Database.<init>(Database.java:16)
    at ip.travelaid.backend.CLITest.main(CLITest.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java:23)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$UiExecutor.<clinit>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:987)
    ... 4 more
```

I have checked both my project and app level `build.gradle` files and they match what the documentation requires, even the Firebase Assistant in AS says that they are right. Just in case though here they are:

Module `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ip.travelaid"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In the Firebase Console I have set up the database to deny any read/write requests but I thought that wouldn't affect my ability to get an instance to the database.
The `google-services.json` file for the Firebase project is up to date, I have even tried re-downloading it from the Firebase Console to no avail.

I have tried searching for a solution online but there seem to be nothing out there on it(this could well be down to me not being able to search for the issue properly though).

Is there a setting, either in the Firebase Console or AS, that I am missing that may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

update compiled & target sdk like so v

```
compiled sdk 26
```

to

```
compiled sdk 28
```

Comment: The reason we don't have the SDK version set to the latest release is because the device I am testing things on only supports up to SDK version 26. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Obligatory: NVM I figured it out.

The problem was that I tried to run the code from the command line and not through an Android Emulator/Device actually running the app.
When I did run it there the problem disappeared.